# Servlet thread pool vs Servlet instance pool - by the web container

Tags: multithreading, servlets, jboss, websphere, web-container

I understand that web containers like jboss have a parameter to mention the number of threads of the servlet to create, which is the maximum number of threads the container can create to run on a Single instance of the servlet.

My question however is, is there a way to specify the number of instances of a servlet to be created? If yes, what is the purpose? The need for this may be to handle requests, when say a thread or threads running on the single instance somehow corrupt that servlet data or destroy() it - Redundancy purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: Watch out ! As of Servlet Specification 2.4, interface 
[javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) is deprecated, with no direct replacement.

The specification is unclear as to whether containers should then create several instances of the same servlet, or always only a single instance.

---

From Servlet Specification 2.4 http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/

> SRV.2.2 Number of Instances
>
> The servlet declaration which is part of the deployment descriptor of
>   theWeb application containing the servlet, as described in Chapter
>   SRV.13, “Deployment Descriptor”, controls how the servlet container
>   provides instances of the servlet. For a servlet not hosted in a
>   distributed environment (the default), the servlet container must use
>   only one instance per servlet declaration. However, for a servlet
>   implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, the servlet container
>   may instantiate multiple instances to handle a heavy request load and
>   serialize requests to a particular instance.
>
> In the case where a
>   servlet was deployed as part of an application marked in the
>   deployment descriptor as distributable, a container may have only one
>   instance per servlet declaration per Java Virtual Machine (JVMTM).
>   However, if the servlet in a distributable application implements the
>   SingleThreadModel interface, the container may instantiate multiple
>   instances of that servlet in each JVM of the container.

You can found in the document more information about Single Thread Model

Comment: I went through that topic in the specification. Things are clearer now with respect to how many instances are created. In essence there will be ONLY ONE instance in a non-dsitributed, non-SingleThreadedModel enivronment. Thanks.